# Vertical list to slide left/right

Tags: jquery, css, slider, slideshow

I've been trying many slideshow scripts but still unable to come up with a way to do below:

I have a list of items that I want to slide left/right on click (similar to many image sliders).  So, if a button is pressed the list a-c will slide out of view and list d-f will then be visible, and so on.

```
[a]     [d]
[b]     [e]
[c]     [f]
```

I have tried multiple ways but am still unable to get a group of vertical items to slide left and right.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Please describe the specific trouble you are having. Adding a simplified http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate the issue will be very helpful. At the very least, you need to add in the code for the sliding part

Comment: If that's the entirety of the functionality you need, it would be trivial to write your own small function to do it. No need for a chunky plugin.